# Does anyone know where this goes in the instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

```json
{
  "Sid": "ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess",
  "Action": [
    "elasticbeanstalk:PutInstanceStatistics"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
    "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a part of the IAM profile for the elastic beanstalk instance.

If you choose AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier or AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier as IAM Instance profile, the ElasticBeanstalkHealthAccess permissions will be added already.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two IAM roles associated with an Elastic Beanstalk Environment:

- Service role: used to manage the environment
- Instance role: role assumed by the running application. It is used to provide access to other AWS services.

You need to find your instance role in IAM console and attach the permission that you see in the documentation. This will allow your application to send statistics.